# Emacs 26.3 on Fedora 31; run on Xming; scrollbars on the left

Tags: emacs, emacs26

Reading the Emacs manual on the GNU website, I found these two variables to set.  I put them in the .emacs file.  If I forget the quote on left, it fails to parse and I get an uncustomized emacs, so I'm sure the code is being evaluated.  I'm very rusty on Emacs LISP and have tried both `'left` and `"left"` and neither work.

It's of secondary importance but having the scrollbar end when the file ends is typical and I think `scroll-bar-adjust-thumb-portion` should make that happen, instead of the default behavior of allowing you to scroll down to complete empty screen on the bottom.

I don't see any other scrollbar customizations in my config except for ctrl-z and alt-z for scrolling a line, and setting colors in in `custom-set-faces`.

```
(setq scroll-bar-mode 'left)
(setq scroll-bar-adjust-thumb-portion nil)
```

Comment: Please specify your platform. Scroll bars in Emacs can be platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `set-scroll-bar-mode`, `setq` isn't enough for this particular variable.  Alternatively, use `customize`.  Note that this info is in the docs for `scroll-bar-mode`.

```
(set-scroll-bar-mode 'left)
```